# How to restrict TAB navigation within the one window widget?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, window, keypress, webix

I have a Webix modal window with a form with several inputs:

```
var form = {
  view:"form",
  borderless:true,
  elements: [
    { view:"text", label:'Login', name:"login" },
    { view:"text", label:'Email', name:"email" },
    { 
      view:"button", value: "Submit", click:function(){
        console.log(this.getParentView().getValues())
    }}
  ]
};
```

The following sample there's a window that illustrates the current behavior:

http://webix.com/snippet/4bd116bb

If I use TAB navigation, focus goes out the window from the last in-window control. Is there a way to localize TAB navigation within the window once the focus gets in?

Comment: If you capture the keyboard events, and check on the last in-window control for the tab, you can simply setFocus() to the first in-window control. Have you read http://docs.webix.com/desktop__uimanager.html#builtinkeyboardevents -- All that said, I've never used webix so.

Answer (score 0):

Code can catch onFocusChange event and move focus back if target is outsideo of the window.

```
webix.attachEvent("onFocusChange", function(target){
  if (!target || target.getTopParentView() != $$("win"))
    webix.delay(function(){
      webix.UIManager.setFocus($$("win").getBody().elements.login);
    });
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/7db250dd